# animated scatterplot by loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to animate scatterplot by loop. I don't want to use `matplotlib` `animation` module because my time interval is variable and thats why i use `time.sleep()` in loop. My code is not working perfectly. It is showing only the first point only. However, while debugging, it showing as intended. Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlim=(10, 90), ylim=(0, 60))
for i in range(1,6):
    ax.scatter(x[:i], y[:i])
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-simple-anim-py

Comment: @PaulH " I don't want to use matplotlib animation module because my time interval is variable"

Comment: @roganjosh pretty sure the animation module can handle that + there's still plenty to learn from the example (e.g., saving the artists and updating their data instead of creating new artists with each loop)

Comment: @PaulH I'm trying to go through the docs now to see, but the example you linked requires a fixed `interval`

Comment: @roganjosh the interval in the OP is a constant, which makes me think that they concept of the interval is misunderstood

Comment: @PaulH yes, I was in the process of editing my other comment after I saw your new one :) It's possible, but it could also be for the sake of simplifying the example (they didn't give `x` and `y` so it does seem an odd simplification to not have a random delay)

Comment: in any case, you can have a baseline constant interval and add to it via the animation function and `fargs`

Comment: @PaulH , if you know how to use variable time interval, please give me an example code as answer. Thanks

Comment: @user3363813 you need to update your example to better express what you're trying to achieve. what determines this variable time interval?

Comment: I think for the sake of the example, one could simlpy assume the question code to use `time.sleep(i)`. But how would you give variable interval to the `FuncAnimation`? I suspect one could change `FuncAnimation._interval` on the fly (e.g. using a class), but that doesn't sound like it's an obvious solution.

Comment: @PaulH The interval is in the data. Its a trajectory Data. So for each coordinate point, there is an associated time.

Comment: You lost me. You always set `time.sleep(1)` why is that?

Comment: @PaulH This is just a test, not the final code. I will put variable time like  `time.sleep(second)`

Comment: you need to make an example that demostrates your problem fully. For instance. This is an easy problem to solve, but I need you to tell me what the problem actually entails

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796314/animate-with-variable-time/) I asked  and see the animation in the answer (consider that as example). The solution is complicated but works, it would be great to have a more simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: it's unclear to me how that doesn't solve your problem. it's not that complicated and you indicated that you understood what was going on.